# How can I understand that the two characteristics of the $\omega$-limit set are equal?

Tags: set-theory, banach-spaces

I have a question about equations (2.1) and (2.2) in the following paper:
[https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdh/IDDS.pdf](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasdh/IDDS.pdf)

The two equations each give a definition of the omega-limit set, but I do not understand how the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: It's preferable to reproduce the equations (and explain any necessary notation) in your question, rather than requiring people to travel off-site to a pdf. But of course you should still include the link to the pdf in your question for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, found the answer here:
[http://www.math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/lec18.pdf](http://www.math.byu.edu/%7Egrant/courses/m634/f99/lec18.pdf)